# Type conversion from Unit to Future[Boolean]

Tags: scala, silhouette

I have the following function and I would like to return `Future[Boolean]` but the IDE prompts that I return `Unit`. I am new in Scala. Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

```
def remove(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Boolean] = {
  val result = findObject(loginInfo)

  result.onSuccess {

    case Some(persistentPasswordInfo) =>

      val removeResult = remove(persistentPasswordInfo._id.toString)

      removeResult.map {
        case Left(ex) => Future.successful(false)
        case Right(b) => Future.successful(b)
      }
    case None => Future.successful(false)

  }

}
```

Comment: return type of `onSuccess` is Unit. `def onSuccess[U](pf: PartialFunction[T, U]): Unit `

Comment: Can u please point me out what I have to modify in order to get a `Future[Boolean]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `onSuccess` with `flatMap`.  Assuming your `remove(x: String)` method also returns a `Future`, that will also need to be `flatMap`ped:

```
def remove(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Boolean] = {
  val result = findObject(loginInfo)

  result.flatMap {

    case Some(persistentPasswordInfo) =>

      val removeResult = remove(persistentPasswordInfo._id.toString)

      removeResult.flatMap {
        case Left(ex) => Future.successful(false)
        case Right(b) => Future.successful(b)
      }
    case None => Future.successful(false)

  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. The error is `Expression of type Future[Future[Boolean]] doesn't conform the expected type _S`. I removed the `Future.succesful()` and I get `Expression of type Future[Boolean] doesn't conform the expected type _S`

Comment: Sorry, just edited it to work as you expect, assuming the remove(x: String) call returns a Future[Either[X]]..  if it doesn't, let me know the correct type signature.

Comment: Can you please help me remove that warning too: `a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
[warn]       case None => Future.successful(false)`. I get it for every `Future.successful` from above.

Comment: You don't need the second `flatMap`, if you also replace the pattern matching with `fold`, you can write : `removeResult.map(_.fold(_ => false, identity))`.